# How to distinguish light-emitting stars and stars that are any visible heavenly body?

Tags: single-word-requests

In French, we have the following words:

- "Étoile", which is a celestial body that emits light (the sun, for example)
- "Astre", which is any type of celestial body that is visible ("étoiles" included)

However, in English, both are translated to "star".

In a context where both ("étoile" and "astre") are used, how may I distinguish both of them?

Comment: Why not just use "celestial/heavenly body" for the general thing and "star" for the specific? But it would depend if you were translating a scientific text, poetry, or something else, which is why it helps to be as specific as possible in explaining your problem.

Comment: Why is the question downvoted without comment...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to note is that you should have given an example sentence that would show how you wished to use the term.

> However, in English, both are translated as "star".

In English, the word **star** is used, understood and translated **in accordance with the context.**

*Astre* is translated as **star** in a (i) superstitious, (ii) literary, or (iii) casual/informal sense:

> (i) Être né sous un astre favorable = *to be born under a lucky star.* (Larousse.)

> (ii) *The stars at night / Are big and bright / Deep in the heart of Texas* (popular song)

> (iii)2023 Greybeard EL&U *"That star next to the moon is Venus."*

In the context above, of the nocturnal sky, any point of light can be referred to as a star.

The moon is never referred to as "a star" as it is not a "point".

The sun is only referred to by the use of "star" in a technical sense - otherwise, it is "the sun." It is not a "point".

In a technical context and for precision, the correct term is used. Meteoroid, comet, asteroid, moon, planet, star. (A star is the only body that emits its own light.)

And sometimes for emphatic effect:

> Harry S. Truman *“I felt like the moon, the stars, and all the planets had fallen on me”*

Comment: I think that outside of a few literary contexts ("morning/evening star") and set expressions ("shooting star"), if you used "star" to refer to a planet, comet, asteroid, etc, you'd get astronomers and anyone with a science education shouting at you. Although of course you may call something a star because you don't know it's a bright planet, but again you might be corrected. (In some fields, such as astrology, it may be different.)

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, celestial body is a common definition that includes also stars:

***[celestial body](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/celestial%20body)***
(variants or less commonly celestial object):

> : an aggregation of matter in the universe (such as a planet, star, or nebula) that can be considered as a single unit (as for astronomical study).

(MW)